# Push notification not work if generate the apk in another machine

Tags: android, apk, cordova-plugins, android-install-apk, android-push-notification

Good day,

I have a mobile project (Cordova app). There are 2 developer working on it. When developer A using his computer to generate the APK file, the app will not able to receive the push notification.

However, if developer B using his computer the APK file, then the app will able to receive push notification.

We cross check the code directory, found that the code of 2 developer is the same, its sync, because all the code is under same git repository.

Any point I can further to check what is the root cause on this? I believe must be something  different configuration out of the code (git repository), but I am not sure what can I check.

Kindly advise.

Comment: check the packge name Are they the same

Comment: Check the contents of `google-services.json`

Comment: Check signing config & SHA-1 at Firebase project